# eclipse adds extra files/folders in project directory?

Tags: eclipse

I just started a PHP project with Eclipe and noticed that it has included a folder outside my project folder called ".metadata", which contains further two folders ".plugins" and ".mylyn".
Also in the project folder it has added ".settings" folder and two files ".buildpath" and .project".
Can I remove all these files once i complete the project?

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse is organized as a workspace that contains projects.  The workspace has the .metadata folder, which contains information local to that workspace (indices for searching, workspace preferences, etc).  The .metadata is never checked into your SCM (at least it shouldn't be).

Each project must have a .project file, that's where eclipse stores project information, what kind of project it is (java, php, etc).  Then each plugin that cares about that project stores their own information in the project (Java creates a .classpath, PHP must create a .buildpath, etc).  When working with eclipse projects in an SCM, those are usually checked in.

If you remove them, then if you ever go back to using eclipse on that project you'll have to re-create them.  But that might be fine depending on your usecase.

Another way to do it is to create a workspace and a project on your local disk somewhere convenient.  Then create a folder and use the Advanced button to point to your source tree somewhere else on disk.  That way, the .project and other files are not in your source tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your project as Eclipse project, if you have completed it, then you can remove that folders and files. Otherwise your project would no longer be detected as Eclipse project.